# Como enviar parámetros con Volley y Php en Android Studio

Tags: php, android-studio, android-volley

estoy realizando una aplicación en Android en la cuál ocupo Volley para leer un Json según un "id_tarjeta" correspondiente, para luego mostrarlo en una lista de CardView. A simple vista creo que el id_tarjeta no está llegando al php, pero no he logrado dar con la solución o el error cometido.

Acá les dejo mi código:

ComponentesActivity.java

```
public class ComponentesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
Toolbar toolbar;
String id_tarjeta="D57990AE";

private static final String URL_DATA = "http://equilibratechile.com/login/consultar_componentes.php";

private List<ComponentesItem> listItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_componentes);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));



    listItems = new ArrayList<>();

    loadRecyclerViewData();
}

private void loadRecyclerViewData(){

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL_DATA,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("leer_comp");

                        if(success.equals("1")) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject o = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String nombre_componente = o.getString("nombre_componente").trim();
                                ComponentesItem item = new ComponentesItem(
                                        nombre_componente

                                );
                                listItems.add(item);
                            }


                            adapter = new ComponentesAdapter(listItems, getApplicationContext());
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error json", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
    {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("id_tarjeta", id_tarjeta);
            return params;
        }
    };


    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return false;
}
```

}

ComponentesAdapter.java

```
public class ComponentesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ComponentesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<ComponentesItem> listItems;
private Context context;

public ComponentesAdapter(List<ComponentesItem> listItems, Context context) {
    this.listItems = listItems;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_componentes, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final ComponentesItem listItem = listItems.get(position);
    holder.textViewNombre.setText(listItem.getNombre());

    holder.cardView.getBackground().setAlpha(128);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView textViewNombre;
    CardView cardView;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        context = itemView.getContext();

        textViewNombre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);




    }

}

   }
```

ComponentesItem.java

```
public class ComponentesItem {

private String nombre;



public ComponentesItem(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;



}



public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}


}
```

consultar_componentes.php

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {

$id_tarjeta = $_POST['id_tarjeta'];

require_once 'connect.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM componentes_nfc WHERE id_tarjeta='$id_tarjeta' ";

$response = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$result = array();
$result['leer_comp'] = array();

 if ( mysqli_num_rows($response) === 1 ) {
     if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response)) {



$index['nombre_componente'] = $row['nombre_componente'];

array_push($result['leer_comp'], $index);

    $result["success"] = "1";
    $result["message"] = "success";

    echo json_encode($result);
    mysqli_close($conn);
     }
} else {

        $result['success'] = "0";
        $result['message'] = "error";
        echo json_encode($result);

        mysqli_close($conn);

    }



   }

 ?>
```

Comment: Estas haciendo una peticion GET  y recibiendo un POST... el id tarjeta podria ir en la URL y recibirlo con un GET en php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COmo te decia podrias enviar el id_tarjeta en la url para hacer una peticion GET:

```
private void loadRecyclerViewData(){
    String url = URL_DATA+"?id_tarjeta="+id_tarjeta;

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("leer_comp");

                        if(success.equals("1")) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject o = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String nombre_componente = o.getString("nombre_componente").trim();
                                ComponentesItem item = new ComponentesItem(
                                        nombre_componente

                                );
                                listItems.add(item);
                            }


                            adapter = new ComponentesAdapter(listItems, getApplicationContext());
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error json", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Y en PHP recibirlo asi:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET') {

    $id_tarjeta = $_GET['id_tarjeta'];
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono sin problema !!